# gregwar/captchaBundle always message "code does not match"

Tags: symfony

I'm using the bundle of Symfony, Gregwar/CaptchaBundle. Itworks great exept that point: I need to renex the code to make it works, if not i have the message "code does not match".

I'm using it in the regitration form of the bundle FOSUser.

I tried to remove the renew option but it doen't make any change.

This is the code i use in my form:

```
$builder->add('captcha', 'captcha', array('as_url' => true, 'reload' => true));
```

Some one has an idea of how to resolve that? Or maybe there is another bundle i can use to do that?

Thank you and hope i was clear.
David

Comment: If you want a suggestion, I use [https://github.com/excelwebzone/EWZRecaptchaBundle](https://github.com/excelwebzone/EWZRecaptchaBundle)

Comment: Hi tttony and thanks. I'll try it if no answer to resolve my problem.

Comment: Hi Tony, i'm surely going to pass to EWZRecaptcha, but i would like to know if i understand well i need to obtain keys by google? Do i need to have a register domain to do it? thx

Comment: Yes to both questions